# How do I remove implicit passing of self in Python class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance

I've got a set of tests, and I've found that I'm copying/pasting a lot of code from class to class, so I want to make a base class to remove this.

To do this effectively, I need to make the module-under-test's function to call be accessible to the base class.  It seems like it should be simple to do, but what I've found is that if my child class specifies a global variable that is the function to test, the base class, when it calls it, inserts 'self' as parameter zero, resulting in `TypeError: FooBar() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

My Code:

```
import unittest    
import moduleOfFunctionsToTest as uut

class Base_Test_Class( unittest.TestCase ):
  def setUp( self ):
    # Common test suite setup
    return

  def runFcn( self ):
    return self.uutFcn( "foo", self.bar )

  # other common fucntions.

class TheFirstTestClass( Base_Test_Class ):
  uutFcn = uut.FooBar
  bar = "0"

  def test_SomeCode( self ):
    self.runFcn
```

How can I call `self.uutFcn` without `self` being inserted?  I've tried passing the value via a constructor, but that caused other headaches (which I may need to revisit if that is correct path to take.)

TIA!

Comment: Have you tried `TheFirstTestClass.uutFcn(arguments)`? Also saying return = stuff should break things and if it doesn't it's really poor style...

Comment: Something else to consider is making a `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` depending on your needs but at a glance I'm not sure either really fits your needs :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod

Comment: @EliBerkowitz - Thanks! I didn't see that typo.  `return = fcn()` won't work.  I condensed the code.  I typically do `x = fcn(); return x` so that single-step debugging allows you to see the return value before returning.

Comment: Yes, doing `uutFcn = staticmethod(uut.FooBar)` would solve your problem.

Comment: I've found 3 ways to make it work.  1) `@staticmethod` decorator on the function I'm testing;  but it requires a change to the module I'm testing, and I really only want to make changes that fix bugs, not make the code testable.  2) create a function in the child class that the base class calls, similar to creating a base class pure virtual function in C++.  3) @jdehesa suggestion, changing the assignment of uutFcn.

@jdehesa, if you want to make an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve it is using [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) in the definition of `uutFcn`:

```
import unittest    
import moduleOfFunctionsToTest as uut

class Base_Test_Class( unittest.TestCase ):
  def setUp( self ):
    # Common test suite setup
    return

  def runFcn( self ):
    return self.uutFcn( "foo", self.bar )

  # other common fucntions.

class TheFirstTestClass( Base_Test_Class ):
  uutFcn = staticmethod(uut.FooBar)
  bar = "0"

  def test_SomeCode( self ):
    self.runFcn()
```

This works because [`staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod) ensures that the given function is always executed with no additional parameters, no matter whether you call it through the class or an instance, so the signature of `uut.FooBar` would remain unchanged.